# What is the use of postMessage in HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the [demo](http://html5demos.com/postmessage), you can post message use code like this:

```
addEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0], 'submit', function (e) {
    if (e.preventDefault)
        e.preventDefault();

    win.postMessage(
        document.getElementById("message").value,
        "http://html5demos.com"
    );

    // otherwise set the returnValue property of the original event to false (IE)
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
});
```

But why is this useful?

At which place should we use `postMessage`?

Comment: `win` is actaully a `background worker` in javascript. when you need to send messages to UI, you use post message to update something on UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about Web Workers, and they are pretty useful.

If you use a normal webpage with Javascript to do a big calculation, your browser will freeze until the calculation is finished. If you use Web Workers however, the browser won't freeze, because the code is executed on a separate thread.

---

In the example of html5demos, an iFrame is used as background worker. For better (and more useful) examples, take a look at this [**blog post**](http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/) of John Resig